# nodejs, Express Cannot GET /

Tags: node.js, apache, express, http-status-code-404

I try to run simplest Express code on Cloud server

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/test', (req, res) => res.send('Hello ')); 
app.listen( 3000 );
```

I am getting the Apache  404  error : `GET /cood180119/projExpress1/demo1/test HTTP/1.0`,  Cannot GET /cood180119/projExpress1/demo1/test

I have noticed that my url is http://77.xx.xx.xx/cood180119/projExpress1/demo1/test

while error logs shows IP : 88.xx.xx.xx.

How to resolve?

I have a node hello world example, which is working with the following url:

`http://77.xx.xx.xx/node-hello-world-master/`

where the file is in `public_html/node-hello-world-master/app.js`,

but does not work with http://77.xx.xx.xx:3000/

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.end("Hello, World!\n  port= ' + process.env.PORT);
}).listen(process.env.PORT); //is says that port is undefined
```

I set the port=3000 in environmental node variables.
After this, i can get the port number echoed , but i still can not access webpage using ttp://77.xx.xx.xx:3000/

Seems firewall is configured wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are requesting the wrong URL.

`app.get('/test', (req, res) => res.send('Hello  '));
app.listen( 3000 );`

this will always produce a route as follows 
'`http://ip:3000/test`

why do you use **cood180119/projExpress1/demo1** in your URL. I don't see any route defined for that.

Comment: This is how url can be formed in other way, by showing the folder structure to the app.js  . I have updated the question, because it still does not work, and seems the reason is the port. how to get the number of the port?

Comment: I have a node application without express, it works if url is folder structure type, but does not work if i put port. Seems i provide the wrong port number. Hos to get the port number?

Comment: Cloud server means? AWS or Some other cloud provider?

Answer (score 0):

Your route

> app.get('/test', (req, res) => res.send('Hello '));

make sure that the `URI` (or the path in this case `/test`) of the request you want to capture exists.

Answer (score 0):

My problem:

**The name of html file was not exactly "index.html"**

So, I renamed it and it worked perfectly!

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Note: public is a folder inside my server directory witch contains index.html and styles.css.